# My magento module not approved as extension

Tags: magento

My Free Community Extension is not approved by magento commerce.

you can get my packaged zip file of my extension from the following url:

202.65.129.178/jungleextn/Junglee_Exports-1.0.0.tgz

when i install this extension with the packaged zip file in magento admin connect manager it gets inatlled and working fine. So i posted it in magento connect. but they are not accepting it. i think there is an issue with extension key, channel, version numbers.

plz can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You may ask the Magento support team they can help you probably.
( http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/overview )
else ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking )

Edit:

Found something ... Use a different name for your Upload. The Package Info Name used when creating the package should be the same as the Extension name when uploading.

Comment: i didnt get u Silom can u please briefly elaborate your answer